# mongodb symfony user authentication?

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Is there any way to implement a MongoDB/Document/User based authentication on Symfony2 ?

Currently on security/providers we have the type "entity:" type which depends on doctrine-orm, but obviously cant be used with mongodb-odm Documents.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at FOSUserBundle [ https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md ]

After installation you will have an extra security provider called `fos_userbundle`

It is build on top of symfony's security system and can be used with Doctrine ORM, Mongodb ODM and Couchdb ODM and it will do a lot of work for you related to user persistence and editing

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what i was lookin for.!

Comment: and how to do it without that bundle?

Comment: @Gigala I think this might help you http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html#securitybundle-integration